# Scrolling issues with IntelliJ/WebStorm and cmd open?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, scroll, cmd, webstorm

Scrolling on my touchpad works fine (although its speed is so fast on IntelliJ, and only IntelliJ or similar apps? I'm not sure why).

However, whenever I open cmd and I scroll in IntelliJ, IntelliJ doesn't scroll! And when I go back to the cmd window, I see that the cmd window has scrolled. So opening cmd and scrolling in IntelliJ causes scrolling to occur in cmd in the background.

Same issues are happening with GitHub Desktop.

This means I cannot scroll in IntelliJ/WebStorm/GH which is a big problem. Is there any fix for this?

(Laptop: lenovo 710s, touchpad driver: Elantech v11.4.97.2 (latest from manufacturer))

**I found that if I scroll in IntelliJ and Excel is open in the background, Excel will scroll instead of IntelliJ. Why is this?**

Comment: I think a better place for such question would be youtrack.jetbrains.com, since it sounds like a bug.

Comment: @Bohuslav Burghardt that's what i thought at first, but its also happening to GitHub desktop. Do they have a framework in Common? Maybe it's a bug in all Java apps? Need to test more. Ill post over there too, thank you!

Comment: This also happens on my lenovo z5070 and git bash command line or nodejs command promt is open. Did you find a solution? Scrolling works fine on an external mouse but touchpad not scrolls

Comment: @iko Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution. I saw there is an update on the Elan driver on the Lenovo website, but haven't tried it yet! I contacted Elan, thinking it is an Elan bug, but haven't received any answer for months.

Comment: Thank you KVR, I went to the site https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds502969 and downloaded the ELAN driver and now it scrolls